# What is a C code fall through and compiling with/without optimization?

Tags: c

I have an assignment that uses these terms and my professor's lecture did not explain them clearly.
I am new to C coding and am having trouble understanding these concepts.

Comment: Hard to tell without more information. Does your professor bite? Why not ask him?

Comment: I was looking more for an immediate answer, but I will ask him when I get the chance.

Comment: Without optimizations the compiler more or less litterally translates your code into machine instructions. Compiling with optimization means that the compiler tries to generate the fastest possible code that still generates the same output (*"observable behavior"*).

Comment: @MikeMB: Or the smallest code, or other optimisation. It is not always speed.

Comment: So compiling WITH optimization is more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fallthough is when a switch case "falls through" to another case:

```
switch(someInt) {
case 0:
    // Do stuff
case 1:
    // Do more stuff
    break;
}
```

In this example, if `someInt` is 0, it will execute both commented sections of code before hitting the `break` statement, which exits the switch. Forgetting to put in a `break` after each switch section is a common beginner error. If you want to make `case 0` only execute it's own code and not the code for `case 1`, it would look like this:

```
switch(someInt) {
case 0:
    // Do stuff
    break;
case 1:
    // Do more stuff
    break;
}
```

Compiling with optimization simply refers to using the [optimization option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) to let the compiler figure out ways to speed up or simplify the program.